# What if PostgreSql introduce a new function with name "cypher" then how to distingush between cypher and sql query with cypher function

Tags: postgresql, apache-age, opencypher

Currently, the structure of **Apache-age** query is:

`SELECT * FROM cypher(<graph_name>, <cypher_query>)`

I am not sure how PostgreSQL is able to distinguish between regular sql queries and Cypher queries after loading age extension.

For now parsers can differentiate between cypher query and normal SQL queries by looking at cypher function in the from clause of select statement. [We are using this approach to distinguish between cypher and normal queries]

But I was concerned that if **PostgreSql** introduce a new function with the name "**cypher**" for some functionality, let's say that cypher function can be used in from-clause like we use **generate_series** in from-clause in the following example.

`SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS number;`

Then there will be conflict in between. How can we resolve that in development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PostgreSQL introduces a new system function, that function will be in the system schema `pg_catalog`. You can disambiguate between such a function and your function by qualifying the function name with the schema, for example

```
SELECT myschema.cypher(...);
```